# Can TensorFlow Lite models be trained?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

When a trained model has been converted to the TensorFlow Lite format in Python, is it possible to train it further as new information becomes available?

I have tried reading the documentation but it gives me the impression the `tflite` format is for making predictions only.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/on_device_training/overview

Comment: @Gorgonzola Thank you for the link. If I understand correctly, when the model is reloaded and converted to tensorflow lite format, it retains a memory of the original model. This original model is then used to do the training when the .train() method is called. Does this seem correct?

Comment: Yeah, you're on the right track. There are limitations on the lite version, obviously. But explore what it is possible and think about why you are doing it as well. When you get it down, answer your own question.